# Does ZeroBrane Studio support navigate backward/forward?

Tags: zerobrane

I am using ZeroBrane Studio for editing Lua. This is a nice IDE but seems missing one critical feature that cannot navigate backward/forward. Like Alt+LeftArrow/Alt+RightArrow in Visual Studio. This feature is important when I am reading a big project. If it doesn't have this feature, any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only in those cases when the forward navigation is triggered by "Jump to definition". After that command `Alt+LeftArrow` will navigate to the previous location. There is a [ticket to extend the navigation](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/690) to handle more general cases, so feel free to comment and contribute to it.